# What method would be right to encrypt SQLite databases, for use on a PHP server?

Tags: php, flash, apache-flex, sqlite, encryption

I have looked into various ways of encrypting sqllite databases such as symmetric and asymmetric key cryptography, ciphers and hash's, but I am clueless of which would be the best to use to encrypt many sqllite databases for the flash builder - android application I am making.

The process is that a client can make many databases (locally) specified by the company I am working for. For each of the databases I need to stop the user from accessing the databases from outside the app. (I've managed to do this using - SqlConn.open(Encrypt...)) Therefore I encrypt the database to stop the user from accessing it.

Any ideas on the best way i.e. what method to use to create the key to encrypt with, the encryption key must be a byte array and equal to 16 bits in length.

When the user finalizes one of the databases, i.e. selects the database on the app, I wish for them to upload it to a server, where they can decrypt the database and manipulate the data accordingly.

My question is, how can I successfully make a key within the app, transfer it once uploaded and decrypt it using php? (What methods would work?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm unclear if you're question is about Flex/AIR or PHP. Will you be distributing the SQLLite databases with your mobile application; in which case PHP doesn't matter, or will you be storing the encrypted databases on an application server, in which case Flex/AIR doesn't matter?

Comment: Both flex/air and php it is being programmed in, taking the databases from the app, encrypted, and decrypting them in php, so the cross compatibility of reversing the algorithm/method is crucial. The databases will be always on the client device, but when they want them processed, they will be transferred and manipulated on the server

Comment: So, you're sending a database to the web server?  That was not clear to me at all from the question; but re-reading it; you do state it.  I don't have the knowledge to help you, though.  best of luck!

Comment: Thanks anyway, know someone who maybe could help?

Comment: Is it just me, or can't flex-AIR apps be decompiled/decoded? I know flash/SWF can be. Therefore, any security you add to your flex application can be by-passed if the person really wants too. The only way you can secure you're database is to have it on your own server behind PHP.

Comment: @Xeoncross Anything can be decompiled/decoded. If the source code uses a hard coded key to access an encrypted database; then yes decompiling the source code would expose a vulnerability, because it would allow the hacker to more easily decrypt the database. Whether this matters or not depends on the data you want protected.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing (not encryption) on the ActionScript side for a key can be done
with the [as3coreLib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) 
It provides md5, SHA224 and others.
Somebody has made a [mini app](http://www.flex-blog.com/flex-encryption-md5-sha1-sha224-sha256-hmac/) to demonstrate it..

But sure, it's not absolutely secure or uncrackable.
Look up, for example, "Rainbow tables" on Wikipedia for more information on that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article i found while researching air's encryption method.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS34990ABF-C893-47ec-B813-9C9D9587A398.html

This is the specification of the encryption: Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) with Counter with CBC-MAC (CCM) mode.

In PHP you can use the mcrypt library.

```
mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv)
```

here is the logic to generate a secure key (its in actionscript):

```
    public static function getEncryptionKey(password:String):ByteArray
    {
        var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        bytes.writeUTF(password + "password salt");

        bytes.position = 0; // have to reset to 0 for an accurate hash
        var hashedKey:String = SHA256.computeDigest(bytes);
        var encryptionKey:ByteArray = generateEncryptionKey(hashedKey);

        return encryptionKey;
    }

    private static function generateEncryptionKey(hash:String):ByteArray
    {
        var result:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

        // select a range of 128 bits (32 hex characters) from the hash
        // In this case, we'll use the bits starting from position 17
        for (var i:uint = 0; i < 32; i += 2)
        {
            var position:uint = i + 17;
            var hex:String = hash.substr(position, 2);
            var byte:int = parseInt(hex, 16);
            result.writeByte(byte);
        }

        return result;
    }
```